# Select Yahoo mail Spam folder using python

Tags: python, smtplib, email-client

I have been a able to select gmail spam folder and outlook spam folder using this code

```
'[Gmail]/Spam' and 'Junk'
```

but i have not been able to do the same for yahoomail

the below is my code

```
smt = 'imap.mail.yahoo.com'
with MailBox(smt).login('******@yahoo.com', 'password', initial_folder='Inbox') as mailbox:
    for f in mailbox.folder.list():
        print(f)
```

Below is the result of this code

```
{'flags': ('\\Archive', '\\HasNoChildren'), 'delim': '/', 'name': 'Archive'}
{'flags': ('\\Junk', '\\HasNoChildren'), 'delim': '/', 'name': 'Bulk Mail'}
{'flags': ('\\Drafts', '\\HasNoChildren'), 'delim': '/', 'name': 'Draft'}
{'flags': ('\\HasNoChildren',), 'delim': '/', 'name': 'Inbox'}
{'flags': ('\\Sent', '\\HasNoChildren'), 'delim': '/', 'name': 'Sent'}
{'flags': ('\\Trash', '\\HasNoChildren'), 'delim': '/', 'name': 'Trash'}
```

I really don't know how to go about selecting the spam folder, i really need this help please.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
with MailBox(SMTP_SERVER).login(FROM_EMAIL, FROM_PWD, initial_folder = 'Bulk Mail') as mailbox:
    # EXISTS: check is folder exists (shortcut for list)
    current_folder = mailbox.folder.get()
    subjects2 = [msg.subject for msg in mailbox.fetch()]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Bulk` works for me.

Folders tree for me:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Archive",
    "flags": {},
    "path": "Archive",
    "subscribed": true,
    "listed": true,
    "specialUse": "\\Archive"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bulk",
    "flags": {},
    "path": "Bulk",
    "subscribed": true,
    "listed": true,
    "specialUse": "\\Junk"
  },
  {
    "name": "Draft",
    "flags": {},
    "path": "Draft",
    "subscribed": true,
    "listed": true,
    "specialUse": "\\Drafts"
  },
  {
    "name": "INBOX",
    "flags": {},
    "path": "INBOX",
    "subscribed": true,
    "listed": true,
    "specialUse": "\\Inbox"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sent",
    "flags": {},
    "path": "Sent",
    "subscribed": true,
    "listed": true,
    "specialUse": "\\Sent"
  },
  {
    "name": "Trash",
    "flags": {},
    "path": "Trash",
    "subscribed": true,
    "listed": true,
    "specialUse": "\\Trash"
  }
]
```